# Failed to build project with react-Native-firebase

Tags: react-native-firebase

The project used to built but recently broke. Diagnostic:

```
:@react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir 
/<PATH>/node_modules/react-native/android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > 'org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'
```

Gradle 6.4.1,
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.1.4",

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by updating to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```